# How can I pass a password to pg_dump 10 when . pgpass in home directory is not an option?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, pg-dump

I am running a cron job that creates a database dump using the `pg_dump` command, like so:

```
export PGPASSWORD="XXXXXXXX"; pg_dump -h localhost -U my_user my_db > /tmp/db_dump.sql
```

But when I run this command, I get a password authentication error:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "my_db" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "my_user"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "my_user"
```

I am not able to place a `.pgpass` file under the user that's running the cron, but I could place it elsewhere and specify the `PGPASSFILE` like so:

```
export PGPASSFILE=/path/to/.pgpass; pg_dump -h localhost -U my_user my_db > /tmp/db_dump.sql
```

But again this returns the same authentication error. I have confirmed that this is not a problem of having the wrong password, because it works when I use the interactive prompt:

```
pg_dump --password -h localhost -U my_user my_db > /tmp/db_dump.sql
Password: XXXXXXXX
```

When I look at the documentation, it looks like `PGPASSWORD` and `PGPASSFILE` are missing from the environmental variables (Perhaps they were removed?) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-pgdump.html

If I can't create a `.pgpass` file located in the home directory of the user running the script, how else can I run the `pg_dump` command?

For context, I am running `pg_dump` version 10.6:

```
pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
```

Comment: The first command should work. I would assume you simply specified the wrong password. Another option is to specify a complete [connection URL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#id-1.7.3.8.3.6)

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the problem, it works when I enter the password into the interactive prompt. I'll update the question to add that detail!

Comment: Did you try to remove the double quotes from the `export` command? Setting `PGPASSWORD` **does** work, I am pretty sure you are passing a wrong password for some reason.

Comment: I had to keep quotes because the password has special characters in it, but switching to *single* quotes did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your original statement will work if all `$`, `?`, `*`, `"` and `\` are properly escaped.

Using single quotes rather than double quotes is the better solution, as a_horse_with_no_name suggested in a comment:

```
export PGPASSWORD='XXXXXXXX'; pg_dump -h localhost -U my_user my_db > /tmp/db_dump.sql
```

An alternative that is usually better is to use a [password file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html).

Using a password is always nasty because it has to sit around in clear text.

There are alternatives, like using `trust` authentication (with a very limited `pg_hba.conf` entry) or certificate authentication.

Comment: another alternative from Laurenz Albe: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/325310/252922